# Programatically create tables in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example Data Frame

```
import pandas as pd
from prettytable import PrettyTable

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["name"] = ["Nick","Bob", "George", "Jason","Death"]
df["Restaurant Manager"] = ["Sam","Mason", "Sam", "Mason","Mason"]
df["Score"] = [1,5, 7, 2,10]
df['Percentile Rank'] = [0,50,80,20,100]
df["Restaurant Name"] = "Elise"
```

What I am trying to do is to recreate this table (see screenshot) that we have in excel since we are in the process of trying to automate our reporting system.

[image]

I managed to get something a bit similar to this but I am stuck... Here is the following code:

```
#Add headers
column_names = ["Rank","Employee Name", "Score", "Percentile"]#Add columns
tb1.add_column(column_names[0],[1,2])
tb1.add_column(column_names[1],["Nick","George"])
tb1.add_column(column_names[2],[1,7])
tb1.add_column(column_names[3],[0,80])
tb1.title = "Elise"
print(tb1)
```

Not only would I like to replicate the table fully as in the image shared above. But I would also like to create multiple similar tables for each restaurant name and place them side by side if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Create it from a dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["Nick","Bob", "George", "Jason","Death"],
    "Restaurant Manager": ["Sam","Mason", "Sam", "Mason","Mason"],
    "Score": [1,5, 7, 2,10],
    'Percentile Rank': [0,50,80,20,100],
    "Restaurant Name": ["Elise", "Elise", "Elise", "Elise", "Elise"]
})
```